# How To Make A Horizontally Scalable Git Solution

Tags: git, ubuntu, scalability, horizontal-scaling

So I've successfully set up my own git server. A little background on it is:

Server: Ubuntu
Git Serice: Gitolite
Web Interface : GitWeb

Now a bunch of projects are going to be added to this server, my 10gig instance will easily be used up. My question is how can I now scale horizontally since git stores all the files on the file system?

Answer (score 0):

Since all the repos (projects) are independent, it seems the obvious solution would be to partition the repos among several backend servers.

Of course, there's a lot more to it than that. For some more detail, check out how github works at https://github.com/blog/530-how-we-made-github-fast . I wouldn't be surprised if github were the largest git hosting platform on the planet, so if you adopt something similar to their approach I'd guess you're unlikely to run into scalability issues.

(And no, I wouldn't worry about that 10gig network connection(?) just yet..)

Comment: Thanks, and no I meant 10 gig of disk space on my server instance.

Comment: @DevinDixon: Ah, in that case I'd advice to instead just get more disk space for your instance. Horizontal scaling is certainly doable but A LOT more work to set up and keep running..